# optimization of number of cylinders in a cube

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I must admit that mathematics is not quit my strongest skill, so I want to ask you from where should I start with a kind of simple problem. Please keep in mind that I'm just a newbie asking things that are not very clear for him.

Let's say I have a room, which is a cube or a rectangular parallelepiped with given dimensions. I need to stick in it cylinders of different sizes in an optimized way. From what I read on the internet for the optimization part I could use [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/). At this moment I don't know from where should I start with this problem of [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Thank you.

Comment: So, you have the dimensions of the room, and the dimensions of the cylinders, and you want to pack as many cylinders as possible into the room? This sounds like a [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem), and those are generally very hard to solve.